# Get value from property if not empty, otherwise get other property with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq query with which i get data from an object like so:

```
var attachedItems = items.ToDictionary(
                               w => w.Number,
                               w => w.Attachments.Select(a => a.Name).ToArray()
                    );
```

This works fine so far, but sometimes the `Attachments.Name` property is empty. Then i'd like to get the value of another property.

To illustrate:

```
var attachedItems = items.ToDictionary(
                               w => w.Number,
                               w => w.Attachments.Select(a => a.Name).ToArray()
                               // If Attachments.Name == Empty, then get
                               w => w.EquipmentCode
                    );
```

How can i do this in a Linq query?

Comment: It's not clear whether you mean "there are no attachments" or "the attachment name is empty".

Comment: Have you changed the question, i'm fairly sure that you have aded `.Name == Empty` later, haven't you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var attachedItems = items.ToDictionary(
       w => w.Number,
       w => w.Attachments.Select(a => a.Name)
                         .DefaultIfEmpty(w.EquipmentCode)
                         .ToArray()
                );
```

This retrieves all attachment names, if no attachments are there, an array with a single item containing the `EquipmentCode` value is returned.

If the `EquipmentCode` property is defined on the `Attachment` and you need it as fallback value for each attachment, then check Jon Skeet's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you just want the conditional operator:

```
var attachedItems = items.ToDictionary(
      w => w.Number,
      w => w.Attachments.Select(a => string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Name) 
                                     ? a.EquipmentCode : a.Name)
                        .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make your Select statement use a lambda and manually check the property like so:

```
var attachedItems = items.ToDictionary(
                               w => w.Number,
                               w => w.Attachments.Select(a => {
                                 if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Name) == false) 
                                    return a.Name; 

                                  return a.EquipmentCode;
                              }).ToArray()
                     );
```